# Join Expression not supported on inner join in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I got the 'Join expression not supported' error on the inner join (If I delete it, it works fine with the right join only), and after hours of investigating, still no clue why.

```
SELECT a.account_id,
       Sum(t.amount) AS SumOfamount
FROM (tbl_input AS t 
right JOIN tbl_account AS a ON t.account = a.account_id)
inner join tbl_cid c on (c.cid = t.cid and c.segment not like 'VGE')
WHERE a.account_id In ('R1001', 'R1002', 'R1004', 'C1001', 'C2001', 'C2003', 'C3003')
GROUP BY a.account_id, t.hfm_classification
ORDER BY 
IIf([a.account_id]='R1001',0,
IIf([a.account_id]='R1002',1,
IIf([a.account_id]='R1004' And [t.hfm_classification]='MDS',2,
IIf([a.account_id]='R1004' And [t.hfm_classification]='M2M',3,
IIf([a.account_id]='R1004' And [t.hfm_classification]='Fixed',4,
IIf([a.account_id]='C1001',5,
IIf([a.account_id]='C2001',6,
IIf([a.account_id]='C2003',7,
IIf([a.account_id]='C3003',8)))))))));
```

Comment: MS Access 1) requires inner joins written before outer joins, 2) doesn't allow using constant expressions in join conditions. You 'violated' both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RIGHT JOIN` can be written as a `LEFT JOIN` and I think that this is what you want also for the 3d table:

```
SELECT a.account_id,
       Sum(x.amount) AS SumOfamount
FROM tbl_account AS a LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_input AS t INNER JOIN tbl_cid AS C
  ON c.cid = t.cid
  WHERE c.segment <> 'VGE'
) AS x ON (x.account = a.account_id)
WHERE a.account_id IN ('R1001', 'R1002', 'R1004', 'C1001', 'C2001', 'C2003', 'C3003')
GROUP BY a.account_id, t.hfm_classification
ORDER BY....
```

Comment: I can not use left join on tbl_cid because it keeps the rows from tbl_input where c.segment = 'VGE', and that's exactly what I want to avoid with inner join.
(overwriting this left join to inner join provides the same error)
Can you advise please?

Comment: If you don't use left join on tbl_cid then you lose all the non matching rows from tbl_account.

Comment: Yes but I need tbl_cid because the segments are there, and I need to filter them

Comment: receiving the same recordset with this. There are still rows which are related to the VGE segment in the tbl_CID

Comment: How is it possible? The condition `WHERE segment <> 'VGE'` does not return rows with `segment=VGE`!!!

Comment: I do not really know. Currently in the tbl_input I only have CIDs which are in the VGE  segment. So by running this I should only see the tbl_accounts values with null values next to them. But I see all the numbers I have in tbl_input. I do not understand

Comment: This code does not apply the condition <> 'VGE' in the table `tbl_input` but in the table `tbl_cid`. So in `tbl_cid` you must not see 'VGE'.

Comment: I understand, but as it is a left join, it keeps everything from tbl_input+tbl_account joined together, and if there is a match with tbl_cid then it joins the values. As I only have VGE values in table input, and there is no VGE in tbl_cid with the filter segment <> VGE, this join does nothing. Thats where we would need the inner join again, but the same error. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If you copied my code, I had a typo: INER instead of INNER. Maybe this was the syntax error. As for your code if it works then fine.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access is fickle about join conditions.

In your case, the `inner join` is turning the outer join into an inner join anyway, because:

- The `right join` keeps all rows in `a`.
- Unmatched rows in `t` are set to `NULL`.
- The `join` condition for `c` uses `t`.  `NULL`s will fail that comparison.

So you might as well express the whole logic as inner joins.

Then it is obvious that you can move the condition to the `where` clause:

```
select . . . 
from (tbl_account as a inner join
      tbl_input as t 
      on t.account = a.account_id
     ) inner join
     tbl_cid c
     on c.cid = t.cid 
where c.segment not like 'VGE' and
      a.account_id In ('R1001', 'R1002', 'R1004', 'C1001', 'C2001', 'C2003', 'C3003')
group by . . .
```

Comment: It works if I modify the simple join to right join. But my problem is that I need every item from tbl_account, even if there is no match. Thats why I used right join before. But with this code only matching pairs account_ids are appearing. Can you help me to modify the code to see everything from tbl_account where the account_ids are in ('R1001', 'R1002', 'R1004', 'C1001', 'C2001', 'C2003', 'C3003')?

Comment: @Looz . . . This question is about fixing the syntax -- which is done now that the `inner` keyword is added.  If this doesn't do what you want, ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic, and your current query.  New questions should not be asked as comments.

Comment: No it was not about fixing the syntax as it was not I wanted to get. -> There were no new questions, just wanted to tell you what is the problem with your solution.